# How can I reorganize a table's data from being in multiple columns to be across rows while maintaining the same heading (and not creating a new one)

Tags: excel

Currently, the spreadsheet has structured as follows

```
ROW1 Name | Address Info Pt. 1 | Address Info Pt. 2 

----------

ROW2 Name | Address Info Pt. 1 | 

----------

ROW3 Name | Address Info Pt. 1 | Address Info Pt. 2 

----------
```

**I want it to be restructured as follows:**

```
ROW1 Name | Address Info Pt. 1

----------

ROW2 _______   | Address Info Pt. 2

----------

ROW3 Name | Address Info Pt. 1

----------

ROW4 Name | Address Info Pt. 1

----------

ROW5 _______   | Address Info Pt. 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps

initially you have the data like below

[image]

Change it to like this by inserting two more columns

[image]

now cut paste the address pt2 cells below address pt 1 cells

[image]

After that sort the full series by name and add

[image]